# JavaScript References Cannot be Found (Visual Studio)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I am creating an ASP.NET website.

I wanted to move my _references.js file to align with the organization of my project:

[image: Dialog]

However, when I try to build my project, I get the following error:

[image: Error Output]

What am I missing here?